# Do Messages block in Android

Tags: android

Im writing an app which loads data from a rest interface.
for this task i use a service which gets called by the activitys. Those calls are based on the "Message". I do it like that because i thought that just sending a message does not result in a blocking of the UI thread (i used much of the RemoteService example code from the android docs). But it feels like if the UI thread ater sending a message still gets blocked (ui doesnt update until the programflow, caused by the message has stoped).

Am i getting something wrong about the whole idea of the message system ? do i need to start the service in a separate thread to get around this ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending messages with the use of Handlers is not blocking depending on what you do with it.  If you're sending a message to a Service, then immediately sending an http request in the server, then it will block.  If you send a message, then have the service simply post a notification in the action bar, then it won't block.

Services run on the main UI thread.  They do not run in the background, so anything you do in the Service will run on the UI thread and can block it if the Service does a lot of work.

Comment: your scenario is exactly what i am doing. if i understood Salw correctly then Services do not run in every case on the main UI thread.

Comment: No.  They always do.  There are custom classes that wrap the Service class which almost immediately start up a thread so it actually does run in the background.  In effect, it's like the Service isn't running in the UI thread, but it's main component still is.  In your case, you can simply start a thread that handles the http request when you handle the message.  This can be done with generic Java threads or AsyncTask.  AsyncTask would probably be the easiest.

Comment: thats something i dont want to do: opening a new thread for exvery server call. IntentService spwans new worker threads (as you said), it seems that there is not similar class for messages. thats kinda strange.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html  `Looper` can be used in new threads to handle messages.  If you create the message handler in the `run()` method, the handler will be in the thread rather than the UI.  Run `Looper` and the thread will block until you call `Looper.quit()` on it.  Doing this will mean that you only create one thread which will handle the messages every time you send it.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped me a lot. also learned much about multithreading in android while reading the documents.

Answer (score 1):

`Message` is processed by thread that is bound to `Handler` you used to send message. If you created `Handler` from UI thread, then your messages are processed in UI thread. You can use `HandlerThread` or you can use `IntentService`.

`HandlerThread` is thread that has its own looper and you can create new handler from it:

```
thread = new HandlerThread("worker");
thread.start();
handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
```

`IntentService` has worker thread and every start command is processed from worker thread in `onHandleIntent(Intent)`

Comment: as i'm working with Messages this doesn't rely solve the problem. what would you suggest to do if i dont want to switch from Messages to intents ? currently im using a ServicConnection to send Messages. Im doing  exactly what DeeV said. sending a message and executing a http request which then blocks the UI thread.

Comment: `Message` is send via `Handler` and `Handler` uses `Looper` of some thread. By default `Handler` is created using `Looper` of current thread. You can create Handler with different `Looper`. Android has `HandlerThread` class that makes this easier. `HandlerThread` has its own `Looper` and you can create `Handler` from this `Looper`. Then every `Message` send via your `Handler` will be processed by `HandlerThread`. DeeV is right, you should use new worker thread, create `Looper` for it and create `Handler` from this `Looper`. `HandlerThread` only simplifies this, it already contains `Looper`.